# LWJGL can't use OpenGL 3.2 or higher

Tags: java, c++, opengl, lwjgl

I want to learn modern OpenGL, so I have to use version 3.2 or higher.
My drivers are updated and GPU Caps Viewer says I have version 4.3.0.
So everything should be fine.

But I cannot access these versions, neither in C++ nor in Java using LWJGL.

Calling

```
System.out.println(glGetString(GL_VERSION));
```

prints "2.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.2900"  (same goes for C++).

So, why can't I program with GL3.2, even if my drivers use GL4.3?
And how can I fix this?

Comment: What are your system specs? And what strings to you get for `GL_VENDOR` and `GL_RENDERER`? – I've got the suspicion that you're running a Optimus equipped system and drop to the On-Board graphics.

Comment: You seem to be right, for GL_VENDOR I get "Intel" and for GL_RENDERER I get "Intel(R) HD Graphics".

Comment: Thank you, you ware right. After changing the NVIDIA-Settings for the JVM, it works fine. Now Eclipse does not longer use my on-board graphics and OpenGL works.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, since this seems to be an Optimus related problem, and not a programming error, you'll have to configure Optimus not to use the on-board / CPU integrated graphics for your program. If this were written in C/C++ you could simply add this along your `main` or `WinMain` function and be done with it:

```
extern "C" {
    _declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
}
```

But this being running in a JRE that's not an option. I suggest you read this application note from NVidia on the subject: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/gamegraphics/files/OptimusRenderingPolicies.pdf

Comment: If I use this method for C++, Visual Studio still can't find methods like glShaderSource etc. And I can't change the NVidia settings for Visual STudio.

Comment: @Exhauzt: `#include <stdint.h>`, `typedef uint32_t DWORDM`. And stuff like `glShaderSource` has been introduced with later versions of OpenGL which in Windows (and Linux) must be loaded dynamically at runtime using `…GetProcAddress` alike calls; since this is tedious there are loader libraries like GLEW which do the heavy lifting.

Comment: thank you, google said I have to include Windows.h (which I don't want) for DWORD and I didn't find  the right header-file by myself. I use GLFW and GLEW but in none of their header-files are functions like glShaderSource and I have code full of unresolved function names if i try to use modern OpenGL.

Comment: @Exhauzt: GLFW is just creating windows and context, does not extension loading. GLEW prefixes all symbols to avoid namespace collisions and adds a large bunch of preprocessor macros to make things look like the "regular" deal. Could you show your C/C++ code?